# node-minify doesn't give asynchronous behavior

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, minify, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to minify some code with [node-minify](https://github.com/srod/node-minify).

Minification is very long so I need absolutely asynchronous behavior.

When I execute this code on my server :

```
'use strict';

const compressor=require('node-minify');

const start=Date.now();

compressor.minify({
    compressor: 'gcc',
    input: 'server.js',
    output: 'server-min.js',
    sync: false,
    callback: function(err, min) {
        console.log('callback at '+(Date.now()-start)+'ms');
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
    }
});
console.log('next instruction at '+(Date.now()-start)+'ms');
```

I obtain this output :

```
next instruction at 60390ms
callback at 60408ms
```

If all goes well I should have less than 100ms for the next instruction.

So, what's going wrong ??

---

EDIT 1 :

@Sly_cardinal, effectively it is asynchronous, but all asynchronous advantage is lost as callback is fired 18ms after the next_instruction, 60390ms (1 minute) after the minification has been launched.

Here is what behavior I expect :

```
next instruction at 18ms
callback at 60408ms
```

It seems that the minification blocks the node process. As the minification is very very long (1 minute here), it can't blocked the node process and should be started in a new thread/process preferably on another cpu core.

---

EDIT 2 :

Following Sly_cardinal advice, I have added some console.log() in runner.js at the begining and the end of each function. Output is :

```
next instruction at 45272ms
callback at 45278ms
```

NB : I have change to minify the minifying script which is only 15 lines. 45s is extremely slow.

What we could see is that it doesn't go through runner.js.
In compress.js, it seems that there is 2 gcc, so I add console.log() to see which one is used :

```
if( (process.execArgv && process.execArgv.indexOf('--use_strict') > -1) || !utils.isNodeV4AndHigher()) {

  gcc = require('./compressors/gcc-java');
console.log('gcc=gcc-java');
} else {
  gcc = require('./compressors/gcc');
console.log('gcc=gcc');
}
```

gcc-java uses runAsync but not the simple gcc.

```
gcc=gcc
next instruction at 50965ms
callback at 50971ms
```

So I force to use gcc-java by replacing the if condition by `if(true)`.
Here is what I obtain :

```
gcc=gcc-java
enter runCommandLine function
enter  runAsync function
exit runAsync function
next instruction at 3805ms
child { Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn java',
  path: 'java',
  spawnargs:
   [ '-server',
     '-XX:+TieredCompilation',
     '-jar',
     '-Xss2048k',
     '/home/pi/node_modules/node-minify/lib/binaries/google_closure_compiler-v20151216.jar',
     '--warning_level',
     'QUIET' ] }
```

In this case, it goes in runAsync, but it encounters an error.

I have some kind of error if I put back the initial if statement and use `'gcc-java'` or `'gcc-legacy'` instead of just `'gcc'` in the call of `compressor.minify`.

Doom.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. We can see your code is running asynchronously because you are getting the "next instruction" log before the "callback" log (if it was sync then it would be the other way around).

Comment: @Sly_cardinal I have edited my question to precise the problem. Thanks for having pointed this.

Comment: how big is `server.js`?

Comment: `server.js` is 13kB and 422 lines (real lines). The problem is not the time of minification, but the fact that it blocks the node process.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you need it to never block, or can it block after you've done some set of other work?

Comment: It is really odd though - the code for `node-minify` is using `childProcess.spawn` so it shouldn't be blocking: https://github.com/srod/node-minify/blob/1e1325d5f1ad2f5a1d72da65e640be8218d483df/lib/runner.js#L46 Is it possible to put some logging statements in `node_modules/node-minify/lib/runner.js` to see when things are running?

Comment: It's done ! see my EDIT 2 part. Thx.